# Вылетает ошибка при преобразовании в datetime тип

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня а датасете есть колонка df["Время"] типа данных object которую мне надо перевести в datetime. При преобразовании с помозью форматов вылетает ошибка ValueError: time data '05:00:00 - 06:00:00' does not match format '%d %b. %Y' (match). Как мне по другому перевести данные в datetime?

```
print(df["Время"])

0        05:00:00 - 06:00:00
1        06:00:00 - 07:00:00
2        07:00:00 - 08:00:00
3        08:00:00 - 09:00:00
4        09:00:00 - 10:00:00
                ...         
70075    24:00:00 - 25:00:00
70076    25:00:00 - 26:00:00
70077    26:00:00 - 27:00:00
70078    27:00:00 - 28:00:00
70079    28:00:00 - 29:00:00
Name: Время, Length: 70080, dtype: object
```

```
df['Время'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Время'],  format='%d %b. %Y')

ValueError: time data '05:00:00 - 06:00:00' does not match format '%d %b. %Y' (match)
```

Comment: Тут как минимум два времени через дефис

Comment: они в одной  колонке

Comment: Функция split() вам поможет.

Comment: в каком месте ее применить?

Comment: 05:00:00-06:00:00 в datetime типе

Comment: А где  в ваших датах %d, %b, %Y  ??  Вот просто интересно, 06:00:00 -  это какой месяц?

Comment: @ГыггыгФидолобабович, приведите в вопросе результат для первых трех строк примера, который вы хотите получить. Тип данных `datetime64` - состоит из даты и времени. Какую дату (и время) вы ожидаете получить из `05:00:00-06:00:00` ??

Comment: @passant этот ответ я скопировал с гитхаба , мне нужно просто время 05:00:00-06:00:00

Comment: @Гыггыг Фидолобабович пока вы будете просто бездумно копировать - у вас ничего и не будет получаться.  Зачем-же вы привели пример, ЗАВЕДОМО некорректный? Прежде чем что-то делать - надо понимать как это делать. Это все очень подробно и детально расписано в документации. Вы ее читали?

Comment: @passant я до этого читал документацию и своими силами пытался преобразовать в datetime, тоже выскочила ошибка и я полез в интернет как исправить

Comment: Если вы читали документацию, то наверняка знаете, что первым параметром функции to_datetime может быть "int, float, str, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series, DataFrame/dict-like". У вас какой из этих типов в вашем датафрейме?

Comment: `28:00:00 - 29:00:00` - это время на планете Меркурий или Венера? Или это вообще не из солнечной системы?? :-D